# I have a list of 800K emails I want to retrieve from a db where I have read only access - how do I do it?

Tags: sql, oracle

So I have a db with a bunch of member info (7 million records) that I can pull info from. Then in a separate system, I have a list of 800K emials. What I want to do is match all those members in the db to this list of 800K emails. I don't have the ability to create a table in the db with these emails - I can only read from the db.

So my question is, what is the best way to do this? Can I write a sql statement that reads these 800k in to memory from a csv file and then does a lookup comparing against this list? What is the approach? I just want to pull all emmebr info for members who's info are in that external list...

Thanks

Comment: I suggest presenting your problem to the person who controls your access to the db.

Comment: Yes, we will look into a better long term solution (it's actually currently in progress). But I wanted to see if there's a way to do this in the meantime. I'm new to SQL so I'm wondering if there's a way to just read the emails from a csv and then query those emails? Is there any way to retrieve this information without making any modification to the database?

Comment: Can you get the dba to create an external table that will reference the csv?

Comment: In SQL - no, but if it is possible, you can write PL/SQL script. Also you can create PL/SQL table function, which you can use later as source of data in `FROM` clause. Of course, it will work very slow, I think.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a separate Oracle database available where you do have DDL access, you could try creating a [DB Link](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_5005.htm) between the two databases using your read-only account.

```
CREATE DATABASE LINK <DB Link Name>
CONNECT TO <Your read-only account>
IDENTIFIED by <password>
USING <ServiceName or TNS Entry of remote database>;
```

This gives you the ability to build queries in your own database but refer to the 7 million records table in the read-only database:

```
Select * from
emails e -- your local 800K emails table
Join customers@readonlydatabase c  -- read-only table in restricted database
      on e.uniqueid = c.uniqueid
```

Per the documentation, the prerequisites for this setup are:

> Prerequisites
>
> To create a private database link, you must have the CREATE DATABASE
> LINK system privilege. To create a public database link, you must have
> the CREATE PUBLIC DATABASE LINK system privilege. Also, you must have
> the CREATE SESSION system privilege on the remote Oracle database.
>
> Oracle Net must be installed on both the local and remote Oracle
> databases.

Also note that a dblink access is only as good as the account which it uses to connect. So if your account is read-only then your dblink will retain the same restrictions.

Answer (score 0):

Build a huge SQL statement like this:

```
select *
from member_data
join
(
    --Add all the text information here.
    --
    --Up to 32767 values can be stored in this collection.
    select column_value email_address from table(sys.odcivarchar2list(
        'asdf1@asdf.com',
        'qwer1@qwer.com'
        --...
    ))
    --Another 32767 values
    union all
    select * from table(sys.odcivarchar2list(
        'asdf2@asdf.com',
        'qwer2@qwer.com'
        --...
    ))
    --...
) other_system
    on member_data.email = other_system.email_address;
```

It's ugly but it's not that hard to build and it doesn't require any additional privileges.  With a few text processing tricks, maybe a regular expression in a text editor or using Excel to add single quotes and commas, that statement can probably be built in a few minutes.  SQL statements this large are usually a bad idea but it will be fine for a one-time process.